# Opened ground on a new outlet

Tags: electrical

I have an older 1981 mobile home and an outlet in my living room wasnt holding plugs so I replaced it with a new three prong, taking the wiring off the old push in styled plug and connecting them to the new screw on plug as they were on the old one: two white wires on one the left side, one red wire on top right and two black wires on the bottom right, and the copper ground pigtail on the ground screw. I turned the power back on and plugged in my tester and it is reading as an open ground. How do I fix this?

Comment: To clarify, the two white wires on the left side of the new outlet are one to each screw, not both on the same one.

Comment: Did the tester indicate it was properly wired before?

Comment: The ground comes on the bare wire (as you probably know). If the ground was OK on the previous outlet, I'd open it up again and make sure that the bare wire didn't come disconnected somehow. If the bare wire is a pigtail from a wirenut, make sure it didn't come lose there.